# CSS variable height columns

Tags: css, layout

I have created a website, www.unionfamilies.com.

I have a header, a main section consisting of two columns, and a footer.  Currently, I have specified heights for header, main, footer, etc.  I would like to make the site so the header stays on top, the columns adjust to match the height of the longest column, and the footer stays at the bottom.  Can someone help me with this?  I am new to CSS, so please be patient.

Thank you.

Comment: look at CSS3.Everything you ask for is provided.For starting,w3schools is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Corrected properties of some divs.

```
#container {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 770px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#header {
    background-color: #3A50B6;
    background-position: right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 109px;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 770px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#menu {
    background-color: #3A50B6;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    font-family: Georgia,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;
    height: 40px;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
#sidebar {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-width: 0;
    float: right;
    left: 0;
    top: 150px;
    width: 225px;
    z-index: 3;
}
#main {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
    left: 226px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    top: 150px;
    width: 503px;
    z-index: 4;
}
#footer {
    background-color: #3A50B6;
    clear: both;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Georgia,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 3.5em;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 770px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to create a div #wrapper just after your #menu for containing both your #sidebar and #main.

But first you absolutely need to remove all your "position:absolute" in your div ( #header, # menu, #main, #footer, #sidebar, etc).

Then you should add a div #wrapper in your HTML, which will be placed just after your #menu and will contain both your #main and your #sidebar, such as :

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="main"></div>
   <div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

And then you should try to apply this settings :

```
#container {
width: 770px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#wrapper {
width: 770px;
height: auto;
padding: 20px;
background-color: white;
}

#main{
width: 503px;
float: right;
} 

#sidebar{
width: 225px;
float:left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to successfully make each column the same height as its tallest neighbor in CSS. There are JS scripts that will do this for you (gets the height then writes the CSS inline to set a height for all of the columns). As for the rest, just make a few different block-level elements. You can see a little of it here.

http://jsfiddle.net/LGuGM/